where to enable /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/0/memory.usage_in_bytes?
I try to count total memory usage in linux via /sys/fs
For this I've found /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/0/memory.usage_in_bytes in https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/cgroup-v1/memory.html#user-interface
i've enabled CONFIG_CGROUPS and CONFIG_MEMCG  options
export CONFIG_MEMCG=true
export CONFIG_CGROUPS=true

Prepared cgroups
mount -t tmpfs none /sys/fs/cgroup
mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/memory
mount -t cgroup none /sys/fs/cgroup/memory -o memory

But doesn't see /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/0/memory.usage_in_bytes in files.
Where to enable CONFIG_CGROUPS and CONFIG_MEMCG options to show /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/0/memory.usage_in_bytes?
How to enable /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/0/memory.usage_in_bytes
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

List item


Please [edit] your question and start at the beginning. What operating system are you using? Which Linux? On what kind of hardware (desktop, laptop, server, embedded?). And what is it you are trying to do?


export CONFIG_MEMCG=true
export CONFIG_CGROUPS=true


These aren't things you export as environment variables, these are kernel compile time options. So, this makes no sense!
However, doesn't really matter, any modern Linux kernel that you'd get with a "normal" Linux distro will have cgroups enabled.

https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/cgroup-v1/memory.html#user-interface

can do that, but notice that all major Linux distros consider cgroups v1 obsolete and are migrating to cgroups v2, so maybe start with working with that instead!
In cgroup v2, and my guess is that you have that because unless you've specifically built a kernel without, your Linux distro will have that enabled, you can find all the controllers neatly stored in their respective subtree.
Try (after rebooting to get rid of your potentially confused cgroup v1 hierarchy):
mount | grep cgroup2 ## probably already there! 

# only do the next line if the previous printed nothing!
mount -t cgroup2 none /sys/fs/cgroup

ls -lh /sys/fs/cgroup

you'll find  scopes and slices as subdirectories there, and within these, and potentially nested within, memory.* controller entries.
